# Why are my GPRINT directives not being drawn into my graphs?

Tags: debian-wheezy, rrdtool, nagios

I'm using NagiosGrapher 1.7.1 with our Nagios installation. We're using the packages from the official Debian repositories.

The graphs I've been building work fine so far, except for any `GPRINT` directives I use. They're simply not processed at all.

An example of a graph definition would be:

```
define ngraph {
  service_name      CPU Utilization
  graph_perf_regex  cpu_prct_used=([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)
  graph_value       cpu_prct_used
  graph_units       %
  graph_legend      CPU used %
  page              CPU
  rrd_plottype      AREA
  rrd_color         0000a0
}
define ngraph {
  service_name      CPU Utilization
  type              GPRINT
  print_source      cpu_prct_used
  print_description Last:
  print_function    LAST
  print_format      %2.2lf %%\t
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [thread on monitorin-portal.org](http://www.monitoring-portal.org/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=18308), this is an issue introduced in the latest (and last ever) version 1.7.1 of NagiosGrapher.

There seems to be a bug in `rrd2-graph.cgi`. The file contains a section titled `# Adding GPRINTs`, which contains the line `$repeat = 0;`.
Changing that line to `$repeat = 1;` will resolve the issue and `GPRINT` directives will be processed.